# What does semantic code refactoring mean?

Tags: testing, architecture, refactoring, semantics, software-design

I was reading some paper, and came across this term.

What actually is the meaning of **semantic code re-factoring**.

And how is normal re-factoring done usually?

EDIT: And suggest some decent semantic code re-factoring tool too.

Comment: Well, do you already have an idea of what semantic is ? And if yes, what keeps you to understand how semantic a code is and how it can be refactored to be more semantic ?

Comment: No. I don't have much idea. Please explain or refer me to some link.

Comment: Semantic is a very broad concept that can be applied to several fields...  The best start would be [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantics).  If you're into HTML, an easy example would be that in order to represent a list, you use a list tag `<ol>` or `<ul>` while you could basically have the exact same visual result with many different implementations.

Comment: Ok. Now semantic code re-factoring.

Comment: even if I had the knowledge to teach that, this is not the place for such an extensive talk. Maybe you better go to another stackexchange site, for example "programmers"

Answer (score 1):

I doubt there is a strict academic definition of what this term means, but I understand it the following way:

Refactoring means just improving code, making it better. Semantic refactoring means, that you refactor code to make your classes resemble your domain model more accurately. With semantic refactoring you introduce real-world sense into your classes and objects.

You can say, that a good refactoring is always a semantic one and I agree to that completely :)